# What horrible thing does Casey see?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-call

Near the end of [The Call (2013)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1911644/), Casey tries to lock herself in a room to escape from Michael. Michael says something like:

> You don't wanna see this.

When Casey turns around, she seems horrified. Michael then says:

> I told you you wouldn't wanna see this!

What horrible thing does Casey see in that room?

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be the decomposed body of his deceased sister.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know exactly. My guess is that this will be revealed in a deleted scene. However, one can attempt to surmise what it could have been:

1. The bed with the bloody sheets. The walls too have some spatter.
2. Perhaps one of the scalps (not necessarily on a mannequin's head).
3. Perhaps a scalped corpse on the bed. It is possible that Foster rapes the girls (dead or alive) too which would explain the bloody sheets.

Answer (score -3):

I think when Halle Berry sneak in and she went to that room, that is the room where he would dress up the abducted girl and make her look like her sister. I don't understand that why Halle Berry and the abducted girl tangled the guy and they left him? Why dont they killed that SOB in the first place?

Comment: Not exactly much of an answer.